# option list doesn't work with Observables

Tags: html, typescript, angular7

I Have an option list of category to select the category of a book. when i try with observable the option list become empty,but if i try with array it is working fine without any problem.Why it is happening.Is the observable is not suitable for option list.

the below code does not work as we expected!

```
 category$: Observable<categoryModel[]>;


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="option-role">Category:</label>
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="options" formControlName="category" required
      [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submitted && f.category.errors}">
      <option value="" disabled>select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let category of category$ | async" [ngValue]="category ">{{category ?.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.category.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.category.errors.required">Please select atleast one Category</div>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

but if i try the same code with a plain category Array it is working with out any problem.The below code is working with out any problem

```
category$:Observable<categoryModel[]>;
this.category$.subscribe(category=>{
this.categoryArray=category;});


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="option-role">Category:</label>
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="options" formControlName="category" required
      [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submitted && f.category.errors}">
      <option value="" disabled>select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let category of categoryArray" [ngValue]="category ">{{category ?.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.category.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.category.errors.required">Please select atleast one Category</div>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is the output of `{{(category$ | async) | json}}` in the template?

Comment: Not tried with that one

Comment: But if tried with another tags like list items it is working with out any problem

Comment: i tried with {{(category$ | async) | json}} ,it showing the data without any problem.

Comment: Would you be able to reproduce the problem on something like Stackblitz?

Comment: Can you add your form control to this example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/option-list-observable. The only difference is the `formControlName` in the template. Can you add that back and add your form logic in the component?

Comment: i added the form logic to the stackblitz and it works perfectly.

Comment: but if i add the same in to the actual one it won't work

Comment: ok its seems to be related to your project specifically and not to Observables. I'm unable to assist if i'm unable to reproduce the problem. Let me know if you fixed it!

Comment: I can show the same observable in the same component as a list item and if i comment it out,option list is working with out any problem